# How to document a class method in python

Tags: python, documentation

I'm looking for a good convention for documenting class methods so that when you look at the definition you can immediately tell what class the method belongs to. For example, if the class definition is 1000 lines long, then how can we clearly show that it belongs to the class.

```
def f(self, x):
    pass
```

Ideally, there is a solution that comes from a standard. A possible solution is to mimic c++ scope:

```
def f(self, x):
   """ExampleClass::f: example method"""
```

Comment: Methods are just functions, so document them the same way. The documentation for the standard library for classes has good [examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) of how to do it and what what to put in them. There's also [PEP 257 -- Docstring Conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/). Python is not C++.

Comment: Right, but my point is that it would be helpful to automatically see what class the method belongs to, otherwise I have to scroll up for a very long time to see the class name.

Comment: I usually don't put the method's name in its docstring. But if I did, I would used `class.method`, not `class::method`—because the latter isn't valid Python syntax. The PEP's are just guidelines and like they say in [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) — [A Foolish Consistency is the Hobgoblin of Little Minds](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds).